gum arabic - capitalized or not?
Should it be gum Arabic or gum arabic in a scientific article? Why? Is there a rule in the Chicago Manual of Style for this case?

BBC news, The Guardian, LA Times, Reuters, Al Jazeera, seem to use lower case, but I can find both versions on CNN and in academic journals.

Why should scientific articles adhere to CMoS recommendations? It's quite likely, in fact,
that different institutions will have style guides with different requirements.

Neither Oxford English Dictionary (login required) nor Merriam-Webster capitalizes arabic in gum arabic.
And here’s what The Chicago Manual of Style has to say:

8: Names, Terms, and Titles of Works
8.61: When to lowercase words derived from proper names Personal, national, or geographical names, and words derived from such names,
are often lowercased when used with a nonliteral meaning. . . .
anglicize arabic numerals arctics (boots) bohemian
bordeaux brie brussels sprouts burgundy [etc.]
Source: The Chicago Manual of
Style (login required)


There is no "rule". The capitalisation is a matter of style or opinion. The question can be answered by reference to available resources: Google Ngram viewer gives an idea of the frequency of capitalisation of either or both of the words - (some adjustment should be made for the capitalisation of "gum" where it starts a sentence.)

Since it isn't being used to distinguish it from gum European or gum American (which don't exist, AFAIK), and it has been used as a common name for the stuff for a very long time, it passes as a "trivial name" - what birders or botanists would call a common name. The modern take on this is to not use capitals even with words based on proper nouns or adjectives. See IUPAC naming conventions.

Fuller's earth is a term for various clays used as an absorbent, filter, or bleaching agent. Products labeled fuller's earth typically consist of palygorskite (attapulgite) or bentonite.[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuller%27s_earth

The entry in M-W is not capitalized, and only 1 out of 5 examples in the current  (computer-compiled) examples there has a capital letter.
